# Get ContentType by "internal name" through REST/JSOM

Tags: 2013, content-type, rest, client-object-model

I understand content types has nothing equivalent to fields internal name, they only have **Name**, which is like a title.
This can be changed, and alters between locales.
My impression is that the safe approach is to use **ID**, however it would be nice to use some kind of internal name, and so my question is: *Is there any internal name-like solution I can use (filter by and read) in REST/JSOM, and if so how?*

I've been experimenting some myself, and this is what I got so far:
When I create a content type, I can specify a name, and this name is stored in **SchemaXml** like this (NAME):

```
<ContentType ...><Folder TargetName="_cts/NAME"/></ContentType>
```

This value does not change, even with different local resources.
I'm able to `$filter` by this value, although I'm only able to do that through **SchemaXml**, which is quite bad. I'm also only able to read the value by parsing **SchemlaXml**, yet again quite bad.

Example: `_api/Web/AvailableContentTypes?$filter=substringof(%27Item%27,SchemaXml)`. Applies to `List/ContentTypes` and `Web/ContentTypes` as well.